# Database implementation of formatting

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, formatting, relational-database

I have database like this:

```
text_id | sentence_id | word_id | word   | meaning

   4          2           124      I         Ja
   4          2           124     like      lubię
   4          2           124     trains.   pociągi
```

Where "Ja", "lubię" , "pociągi" are unique translation in particular context.

The thing is that I need sometimes, format this text, this is for example 
bold the word "trains" in on my website. Or surround one of the sentences with:

```
<h1> </h1>
```

tag.

I have no idea how to save information about formatting in a not obtrusive way.

Thanks for help.

PS: I need no fancy formatting, I just need save information about new paragraphs "p" headers  "h1" "h2" and so on.

Maybe I would like to save information about image that is between particular sentences.

PS2: I use MySql.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you look to take the information in the database and export it out into an HTML file of some sort.

In order to do this you must:

1) Retrieve the information from the database using a query similar to the following.

```
   $query = SELECT word, meaning FROM $dbname
```

2) Style those fields using something similar to the following.

```
   echo <h1 class="field"> <?php echo $resultsFromQuery ?> </h1>
```